# Changing BibLaTeX bath-style bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, harvard-style

I am currently working on my Bachelor's thesis and have pretty strict requirements for the bibliography. As I must use Harvard citation, I am using the bath-style.

For my online sources I need to put the word "online" in square brackets. (Bath standard is bold, but without brackets.

For example my current entry looks like this:

> Airbus S.A.S., 2021. *Worldwide Presence: Airbus in Deutschland* **online** Abger. unter: https://www.airbus.com/company/worldwide-presence/germany/germany-de.html [besucht am 19. Jan 2021]

However, it should look like this:

> Airbus S.A.S., 2021. Worldwide Presence: Airbus in Deutschland [online] Abger. unter: https://www.airbus.com/company/worldwide-presence/germany/germany-de.html [besucht am 19. Jan 2021]

If anyone has some experience in working with this style and change such specific things about it, help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that technically speaking "Harvard style" does not refer to a single well-defined style: It refers to a class of author-year styles. (This is unlike APA style or Chicago style, which refer to well-defined styles.) Your version of Harvard style is likely to be different from other people's Harvard style.

Comment: `biblatex-bath` is a style that was written specifically to implement the style prescribed by the University of Bath. It was not intended as a basis for custom styles. You can modify it to some extent, but some modifications might be trickier than with the standard styles. (Though `biblatex-bath` is much closer to the standard styles than `biblatex-apa`.) Usually I recommend to take the standard styles as basis for a custom styles. But if `biblatex-bath` comes really close to what you need, it may still be a good basis for your style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see your only problem is that `biblatex-bath` does not speak German. The style defines a few additional bibliography strings that are not present in standard `biblatex`. One of those strings is `online`, which is used here.

If you give the German translation of that string with `\DefineBibliographyStrings` you get something that looks pretty much like described in the question.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=bath]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{
  online = {online},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{airbus,
  author    = {{Airbus S.A.S.}},
  title     = {Worldwide Presence: Airbus in Deutschland},
  year      = {2021},
  url       = {https://www.airbus.com/company/worldwide-presence/germany/germany-de.html},
  urldate   = {2021-01-19},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,airbus}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Airbus S.A.S., 2021. Worldwide Presence: Airbus in Deutschland [online]. Abger. unter: https://www.airbus.com/company/worldwide-presence/germany/germany-de.html [besucht am 19. Jan. 2021].]

---

In addition to `online` `biblatex-bath` also defines the strings `hours`, `at`, `unpublished`, `legalchapter`,
`director`, `performer`, `reader`, `conductor`,
`directors`, `performers`, `readers`, `conductors`,
`bydirector`, `byperformer`, `byreader`, `byconductor`, which you may or may not want to translate as well.

If you want to translate all of those strings, it is probably easiest to graph a copy of `english-bath.lbx` from your file system, rename it to `german-bath.lbx` and translate all terms into German.

Comment: Thank you very much! Together with Oni's answer, I was able to solve my issues. And also for not providing my code, I'm under a thight NDA and want to be as carefull as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Because no MWE given, here is biber settings for getting started:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,%
citetracker=true,%
isbn=true,%
doi=true,%
url=true,%
usetranslator=true,%
style=authoryear,%
citestyle=numeric,%
terseinits=false,%
giveninits=true,%
sorting=nyt% none
]{biblatex}

% set right format
%\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} % deprecated
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}%
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1} % remove () from label number
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1} % title
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1} % remove underline
\DeclareFieldFormat*{url}{\textless\url{#1}\textgreater} % you can modify how to url looks here
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\addcomma\space\bibstring\[{urlseen}\space#1\]} % remove () from urldate
%try set translation to biblio
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlfrom = {available at},%
  urlseen = {visited on},%
  fromenglish = {from English},%
  fromfinnish = {from Finnish},%
  fromgerman = {from German},%
  fromjapanese = {from Japanese},%     
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
urlseen = {besucht am},%
}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}% for biblatex you need out \printbibliography too
%forcing single line spacing in bibliography
\DisemulatePackage{setspace}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use some of your answer and have it working the way I want it to now.